# Unable to write a snapshot test of a component that is calling a moment method within the render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test the following component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import moment from 'moment'
import { SingleDatePicker } from 'react-dates'
import MealList from './MealList';
import { capitalize } from '../helpers/helpers'

export class MealSummary extends Component {
    state = {
        date: moment(),
        calendarFocused: false
    }
    onDateChange = date => {
        if (date) this.setState({ date })
    }
    onFocusChange = ({ focused }) => this.setState({ calendarFocused: focused })

    renderMealCategory = (mealCategory) => {
        return this.props.meals.filter(meal => meal.mealCategory === mealCategory && meal.date.isSame(this.state.date, 'day'))
    }

    renderFilteredTotal = (mealCategory) => {
        return this.props.meals.filter(meal => meal.mealCategory === mealCategory && meal.date.isSame(this.state.date, 'day'))
            .reduce((sum, n) => sum + n.calories, 0)
    }

    renderTotal = () => (this.props.meals.filter(meal => meal.date.isSame(this.state.date, 'day')).reduce((sum, n) => sum + n.calories, 0))

    renderMeals = () => {
        const categories = ['breakfast', 'lunch', 'dinner', 'snack']

        return categories.map(category => {
            return (
                <div key={category}>
                    <h1>{capitalize(category)}</h1>
                    <MealList meals={this.renderMealCategory(category)} />
                    <h4>Total: {this.renderFilteredTotal(category)}</h4>
                </div>
            )
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Summary Page</h1>
                <SingleDatePicker
                    date={this.state.date}
                    onDateChange={this.onDateChange}
                    focused={this.state.calendarFocused}
                    onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
                    numberOfMonths={1}
                    isOutsideRange={() => false}
                    id="caloriEat-meal-summary" />
                {this.renderMeals()}
                <div>
                    <h1>Total Calories Consumed: {this.renderTotal()}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    meals: state.meals
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MealSummary)
```

I have written the following failing test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { MealSummary } from '../../components/MealSummary'
import { meals } from '../fixtures/mealReducer'


describe('<MealSummary />', () => {
    test('should render MealSummary', () => {
        const renderMealCategory = jest.fn()
        const wrapper = shallow(<MealSummary meals={meals} />)
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
    })
})
```

I receive the error:

```
    TypeError: meal.date.isSame is not a function

      17 | 
      18 |     renderMealCategory = (mealCategory) => {
    > 19 |         return this.props.meals.filter(meal => meal.mealCategory === mealCategory && meal.date.isSame(this.state.date, 'day'))
         |                                                                                                ^
      20 |     }
      21 | 
      22 |     renderFilteredTotal = (mealCategory) => {
```

The object meals has a `meals.date` property of which a moment method `isSame` is called on to compare the date within the state.  I have quite a few of these functions within separate calls to render the page correctly.  Why is the function not being recognized? I tried passing a mock function for `isSame` `const isSame = jest.fn()` and passed it as a prop to MealSummary, but it didn't work.  How can I get this test to work correctly with a method that runs from a different (moment) library, so that I can get it to create a snapshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing in `meals` from `import { meals } from '../fixtures/mealReducer'`, we would need to see what is in the reducer, but I am guessing you have something like:

```
const meals = [{ mealCategory: 'breakfast', date: new Date()}]
```

when you should have

```
const meals = [{ mealCategory: 'breakfast', date: moment()}]
```

Comment: I have a link to the repo https://github.com/altafmquadri/caloriEat/blob/master/src/tests/fixtures/mealReducer.js

Comment: The date is saved as a moment string `date: '2020-08-17T18:36:13.173Z',`

Comment: so change it to `date: moment('2020-08-17T18:36:13.173Z'),`

Comment: or keep it and change the component to do `moment(meal.date).isSame`

Comment: the qualifier is optional - `isSame(someDate)` will check if everything is the same (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, etc), `isSame(someDate, 'day')` will check if everything is the same >= day (so same year month and day).  It just depends on what you consider to be "the same" what you should use.

Comment: I see, I was under the impression what was stored in my state was the moment object stored as a string.  I did not know that I would have to apply moment back on the date object within the component.  I am not sure why I have to use moment again in the component, but it does work, so thank you.